# Passing data between unrelated components

Tags: angular

I have three components (news-feed, comment, reply) in my `news-feed.component` I,m doing this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data" id="{{item.post_id}}" class="post_{{item.post_id}}">

//news feed data is fine here but without comments and replys

</div>
```

I'm looking for this  idea:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data" id="{{item.post_id}}" class="post_{{item.post_id}}">

    <app-comment>

     <app-reply></app-reply>

    </app-comment>

<div>
```

How can I pass the `{{item.post_id}}` to other components.

Note: comment and reply components are not child of news-feed.

Comment: Check this http://learnangular2.com/inputs/

Comment: you need to use @input .. check this out https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [@Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) decorator. in your child components use it like this:

```
// app-comment.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component(...)
export class AppCommentComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('someKey') someKey: any;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.someKey);
    }
}
```

And you'll be able to pass data to it like so:

```
<app-comment [someKey]="'someValue'"></app-comment>
```

Comment: he specifically stated that the receiver component _is no_ a child of the sender. He need a service based architecture i think, having a service in between the components wich serves data to both.